# How do i add remote nodes to the gridgain?

Tags: java, mapreduce, gridgain

I am a newbie to Gridgain and i would like to know how do i add remote nodes to a program. is there some configuration file. i dont see a clear cut example anywhere in the guides. (the worst guide i've ever seen)

Answer (score 2):

By default, GridGain uses multicast discovery, so, if multicast is working in your network, nodes should find each other automatically.

You can configure an alternative multicast group address, if default settings do not work.

You can also configure TCP discovery with a list of IP addresses and ports, where nodes can start. This gives you more control over the discovery process, and is also a good alternative, if multicast discovery does not work.

There are also other means of discovery (including Shared FS and Amazon S3). Check `GRIDGAIN_HOME/config/default-spring.xml` for examples (search for "discovery"). Also, have a look at [GRIDGAIN_HOME/examples/config/spring-cache.xml](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/config/spring-cache.xml#L197-L223).

Please ensure you start all the nodes with the same configuration ("localHost" property may differ).

Answer (score 0):

There is work-in-progress book online: http://www.gridgain.com/book/book.html#_taste_of_gridgain

That should answer these basic questions.

Comment: i know how to run on same vm, im talking abt 2 seperate systems connected via ethernet?